# Random Chinese text in "New Document" dialog in right click menu of Nautilus

Tags: nautilus, language-support, context-menu, wps-office

[image: Screenshot]

Should I be worried? I recently upgraded from 18.04.
I checked the language configured in LibreOffice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you're using WPS office (provided by Kingsoft, a Chinese company). These are the default names set by the installer for the product. Below are the translations for your reference.

- 文档 = Document
- 演示文稿 = Presentation
- 工作表 = The worksheet

You can modify the names by editing the corresponding file names in ***~/Templates***.

So, you shouldn't be worried if you have WPS office and trust Kingsoft.